# how to input table as a variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql, dynamic, procedure

I am trying to get data from a table using dynamic procedure with MySQL query.
Is there any way to do it specifically?
I am trying with this procedure below however the variable is still returning as a column.

See code below:

```
DELIMITER $

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS REC_DATA$

CREATE PROCEDURE REC_DATA( IN_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(20) )

BEGIN

    BEGIN

        SET @in_table = IN_TABLE_NAME;
        SET @sql_stmt = CONCAT(' SELECT student_id FROM ' , @in_table);

        SELECT @sql_stmt;
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_stmt;
        EXECUTE stmt;

    END;

END$

DELIMITER ;
```

I am receiving this error: ERROR: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'SCORE' in 'field list'

Someone can help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate this error if I fail to enclose the parameter in the call statement with single quotes.

Comment: Yes! I figure out after that I was calling it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the correct code:

```
DELIMITER $

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS REPORT$

CREATE PROCEDURE REPORT( IN_TAB_NAME VARCHAR(20) )

BEGIN

    DECLARE sql_stmt VARCHAR(100);

    BEGIN

        SET @in_table = IN_TAB_NAME;
        SET @sql_stmt = CONCAT(' SELECT [columns] FROM ' , @in_table, 
            ' GROUP BY [column]');

        SELECT @sql_stmt;
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_stmt;
        EXECUTE stmt;

    END;

END$

DELIMITER ;
```